# Exclude posts with empty post_content in wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, query-posts, post-content

is it possible to exclude posts with empty post content from a wp_query?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    var_dump($post->post_content);
}
```

Doing it inside the loop like `if($post->post_content !== '') { }` is not an option. Because my list won't have 5 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible with a standard WP query, and you'll have to leverage the use of `posts_where` before the `WP_Query` is called.

```
function the_dramatist_filter_where($where = ''){
    $where .= " AND trim(coalesce(post_content, '')) <>''";
    return $where;
}
```

In the above, we're simply only selecting posts where the column `post_content` isn't empty.

Then add the filter.

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'the_dramatist_filter_where');
```

Now perform the query.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 8));
```

And then when you're done, remove the filter from the query so it doesn't interfere.

```
remove_filter('posts_where', 'the_dramatist_filter_where');
```

Comment: I found this solution, too. But it didn't work. Quite the reverse I'll getting a strage result: 3 x posts with empty content, 1 x acf-field and 1 x acf-field-group

Comment: few possible problems with the sql 1. you assume where is not empty 2. probably need a space in the start and end of the statement 3. might need to wrap the condition in `()`

Comment: BTW there is an typing error in your comment: function **fitler**_where($where = ''){ :-)

Comment: Yea.. I'm working on it. Please wait sometime.

Comment: Please try the updated code. Now it would work fine. I've tested it. @snuwie

Comment: @the_dramatist thx! In my test installation it looks good. I will test it on my staging env later this day.

Comment: Sure! I still wanted to wait for my "staging" test (not done yet) ;-) But so long: thank you :-)

Comment: @the_dramatist tested it on my staging env. Worked fine! Thank you! :)